# Problems starting mod_geoip

Tags: geoip

After installing mod_geoip / geoip-api-c with success, I am getting an error trying to re-start Apache using 'LoadModule geoip_module libexec/mod_geoip.so'

```
Error:
*Cannot load /usr/local/apache/libexec/mod_geoip.so into server: Shared object "libc.so.7" not found*
```

My server software is a bit dated but rock solid:

```
Freebsd: 4.7
Apache: 1.3.42
geoip-api-c: 1.4.8_3 (newest package version available on freebsd.org)
mod_geoip: 1.3.5
```

I was not able to build a newer version of the api-c on my server, that is why I ended up using a the package from freebsd.org.

Any help would be appreciated, I really need to get this to work, mod-security / .htaccess alone are not cutting it anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was and I now have GeoIP working on my server, for the sake of other users I'll explain what I did to get this working but... my server setup is unique and other users are cautioned before using this method.

What I discovered was that my version of gcc was to old to successfully 'make' the GeoIP C API so I used a newer version of gcc to 'make' the C API and used that same version of gcc to create the Apache shared object mod_geoip.

Also before starting GeoIP in my httpd.conf file I had to add libgcc_s.so.1 to /usr/local/lib/

I have done extensive testing all day, so far all is well!